# How to code iOS Background Service Triggered via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, mobile, core-bluetooth

I have an accessory that emits a bluetooth signal for 60 seconds in an emergency. I coded an iOS app; The user first pairs the accessory through the application and then closes the application. The application saves the information of the paired accessory (service.UUID.UUIDString and peripheral.identifier.UUIDString). I did this with the "CoreBluetooth" library. I added Background Modes to my project, but my app needs to run in closed state too.

[Project Background Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMi3r.png)

I want to trigger a method on my app when accessory emits bluetooth signal even if my app is not open. How can I do that?

Comment: It is currently working when the app is running in foreground?

Comment: Yes, although it works in background mode, when I close the app, it doesn't work.